# Tyring to update a URL using Curl on Linux

Tags: shell, curl

I am trying to update an ticket and I am trying to do that through Linux. Not sure whether it can be done or not, in the way of searching, I found one blogger sharing, where he/she was also trying to update something

He/She has used the below commands to update the URL.

```
curl -i -u "script-user:password" -X PUT -d "short_description=Update+me"      https:/0005000972
```

I suspect he/she is trying to update the URL with "Update me".
Is that right? or else Can some one explain what that blogger tried to do??

Answer (score 0):

This is a [RESTful](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) request. That is a request using standard HTTP methods (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE) to query a server.

- `-X PUT` specifies the method used
- `-d "...."` specifies the data send to the server
- `https://...` (ill formed in your example) is of course the URL of the target server

Usually, the `PUT` method is used to **replace** an existing attribute/value on the server. As the concrete parameters and/or methods available are service dependent, I can only *guess* here that the intend is to update some attribute named `short_description` to store the value `Update Me` (URL encoded -- or more formally [x-www-form-urlencoded](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.1))

Maybe you should first read a little bit more about those topics, and then, if necessary post an other question describing more in details both the target server and the goal you're trying to achieve on it.